# How to efficeintly copy output from a dataframe in jupyter or colab and paste for stackoverflow with pretty/readable format

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Often, in creating examples for stackoverflow, we need to paste output from a dataframe. Due to spacing and the index not having a column name, these outputs are not usually very readable for stackoverflow. Here's an example

```
A   B   C
0   34  11  57
1   51  13  24
2   37  18  96
3   66  62  87
4   79  17  57
```

The columns are quite aligned, especially with the column names.

There seems to be ways to get over the copy/paste issues, like reading from clipboard, or stringIO, but I haven't been able to see a technique for this particular circumstance.

Comment: The output from `df.to_markdown(index=False)` can be read with `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')`

Answer (score 1):

For small dataframes `print(df)` provides good copy-paste'able output.